# How to create new chat room with play framework websocket?

Tags: websocket, playframework, akka

I tried the chat example with websocket in play framework 2.6.x. It works fine. Now for the real application, I need to create multiple chat rooms based on user requests. And users will be able to access different chatrooms with an id or something. I think it might related to create a new flow for each room. Related code is here:

```
   private val (chatSink, chatSource) = {
    val source = MergeHub.source[WSMessage]
      .log("source")
      .map { msg =>
      try {
        val json = Json.parse(msg)
        inputSanitizer.sanText((json \ "msg").as[String])
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => println(">>" + msg)
          "Malfunction client"
      }
    }
     .recoverWithRetries(-1, { case _: Exception ⇒ Source.empty })

    val sink = BroadcastHub.sink[WSMessage]
    source.toMat(sink)(Keep.both).run()
  }

  private val userFlow: Flow[WSMessage, WSMessage, _] = {
    Flow.fromSinkAndSource(chatSink, chatSource)
  }
```

But I really don't know how to create new flow with id and access it later. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: No one ever tried to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Post the solution here in case anyone has similar problems.
My solution is to use the `AsyncCacheApi` to store `Flow`s in cache with keys. Generate a new `Flow` when necessary instead of creating just one Sink and Source:

```
val chatRoom = cache.get[Flow[WSMessage, WSMessage, _]](s"id=$id")
chatRoom.map{room=>
    val flow = if(room.nonEmpty) room.get else createNewFlow
    cache.set(s"id=$id", flow)
    Right(flow)
}
def createNewFlow: Flow[WSMessage, WSMessage, _] = {
    val (chatSink, chatSource) = {
      val source = MergeHub.source[WSMessage]
        .map { msg =>
         try {
           inputSanitizer.sanitize(msg)
         } catch {
           case e: Exception => println(">>" + msg)
             "Malfunction client"
         }
       }
       .recoverWithRetries(-1, { case _: Exception ⇒ Source.empty })

     val sink = BroadcastHub.sink[WSMessage]
     source.toMat(sink)(Keep.both).run()
   }
   Flow.fromSinkAndSource(chatSink, chatSource)
 }
```